How can I create a VHD-based Dev Drive using PowerShell?
I see many people discussing how to use storageDSC to create a partition-based Dev Drive in PowerShell (also an example yaml config & the PR to storageDSC). Can I create a VHD-based Dev Drive in PowerShell, too?
Something like:
$vhd = Make-AVHD
Make-TheVHDIntoADevDrive $vhd
# set filters, etc...

I know Format-Volume has a -DevDrive parameter, so I think this should work.

You can indeed create VHD-based Dev Drives in PowerShell:
function New-VHDDevDrive
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Path, # e.g. 'C:\test4.vhdx'

        [string]$Size = 5GB
    )

    $vhd = New-VHD -Path $Path -Dynamic -SizeBytes $Size
    $disk = $vhd | Mount-VHD -Passthru
    $init = $disk | Initialize-Disk -Passthru

    # New-Partition pops open explorer to the new drive before Format-Volume
    # completes, so it often tells you to format the drive.
    #
    # > You need to format the disk in drive R: before you can use it.
    #
    # Just ignore the pop-up until the formatting is complete, then click Cancel.
    $part = $init | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
    $vol = $part | Format-Volume -DevDrive -FileSystem ReFS -Confirm:$false -Force
    $vol

    # You can enable filters on this volume, too, like GVFS & Security:
    # fsutil devdrv setFiltersAllowed /F /volume "$($vol.DriveLetter):" PrjFlt,MsSecFlt,DfmFlt
}

Usage:
New-VHDDevDrive -Path 'c:\test5.vhdx' -size 20GB

It should be straightforward to modify this script to support specific -DriveLetters in New-Partition etc.
Appendix: remove VHDs
To remove these VHDs (since you created 20 while testing this):
Dismount-VHD -Path 'c:\test5.vhdx'
Remove-Item -Path 'c:\test5.vhdx'

Also, they seem to take about 450MB each when empty, in case you were wondering.
See also

This answer to a question about initializing new disks put me on the right track
This example on MSDN for New-VHD contains a pipeline similar to the previous question
This post mentions Format-Volume -DevDrive
This post describes New-VHD

